# Django query: transform two for loops into a queryset

Tags: python, django

I have 3 simple models:

```
from django_better_admin_arrayfield.models.fields import ArrayField

class BuildItem(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    mandatory_skills = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)

class Item(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Skill(BaseModel):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="skills")
    effect = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to retrieve the sum of the value fields of the skills multiply by the level field of builditem, where the pk fields of the skills are in the mandatory_field list, if the effect field of skill is equal to 1.

I wrote some code that works with for loop:

```
array_life = []

for builditem in BuildItem.objects.all():
    for skill in builditem.base.skills.all():
        if skill.pk in builditem.mandatory_skills:
            if skill.effect == 1 and skill.value < 2:
                array_life.append(skill.value * builditem.level)

sum_life = sum(array_life)
```

I would like to transform this code into a queryset.
*(I tried many things but without success)*

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how django_better_admin_arrayfield works, but if it's anything like an m2m field, you could do something like:

```
sum_life = sum(Skill.objects.filter(
    effect=1, 
    value__lt=2,
    builditem__mandatory_skills__in=F('pk'),
).values_list('value', flat=True))
```

or

```
sum_life = Skill.objects.filter(
    effect=1, 
    value__lt=2,
    builditem__mandatory_skills__in=F('pk'),
).aggregate(Sum('value'))
```